# Perennial link to a research article

Tags: citations, online-resource, tools

For convenience, I often want to give a link to a research article in addition to the citation. I am mostly look for the following two properties:

- the link should be valid as long as possible
- the link should provide as many sources as possible to download the article, ideally free of charge whenever available.

I use Google scholar, e.g.: *Godbole, Shantanu, and Sunita Sarawagi. "[Discriminative methods for multi-labeled classification.](https://scholar.google.com/scholar?cluster=8646809048732748859&hl=en&as_sdt=0,5)" Advances in Knowledge Discovery and Data Mining. Springer Berlin Heidelberg, 2004. 22-30.*

I link to the "all versions" page:

[image]

Are there other any good/better alternatives?

Answer (score 6):

> the link should be valid as long as possible

There is no guarantee that Google Scholar will even still exist as a service in a few years, let alone that its URL scheme will stay the same. Who knows when another round of [spring cleaning](http://googleblog.blogspot.com/2013/03/a-second-spring-of-cleaning.html) might come?

From the point of view of avoiding link rot, using a DOI resolver seems much better, e.g. http://dx.doi.org/10.1007/978-3-540-24775-3_5

Related: [DOI® System and Persistent URLs](http://www.doi.org/factsheets/DOI_PURL.html)

> Is there any DOI resolver that points to multiple sources, including free ones when available?

Citeseer does this, e.g. http://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/summary?doi=10.1.1.1.3819 - but unlike http://doi.org they have made no commitment to maintain this service in perpetuity. And they don't seem to be using standard DOIs, but their own internal ones.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Yes I agree about Google Scholar, all the more so as Google often closes its services, that's why I'm looking for better solutions :) Is there any DOI resolver that points to multiple sources, including free ones when available?

Comment: @FranckDernoncourt See update

Comment: The DOI system is run by a consortium of publishers and provides redirection to the publisher's copy of a paper- it won't help you find preprints or other unofficial copies of the paper.